# Get Process Info (Current process, parent process, oldest child process)

Tags: linux, struct, process, linux-kernel, parent

I have an exercise about adding a system call in the Linux kernel, but I'm struggling to implement it. Below is the description:

The main part of this assignment is to implement a new system call that lets the user determine the information about current process, the parent and the oldest child process. I manage to do this much but i don't know how to find the the oldest child process.
This is my code:

```
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>

 struct proc_info {
 pid_t pid;
 char name[16];
 };

 struct procinfos {
 long studentID;
 struct proc_info proc;
 struct proc_info parent_proc;
 struct proc_info oldest_child_proc;
 };

 asmlinkage long sys_get_proc_info(pid_t pid, struct procinfos *info){
 struct task_struct *task = pid_task ( find_vpid ( pid ) , PIDTYPE_PID);
 printk("Finding...\n");
 for_each_process(task) {
 printk("[%d] ------- [%s]\n", task->pid, task->comm);
 if(task->pid == pid) {
 struct procinfos buff;
 buff.studentID = 1952598;
 buff.proc.pid = task->pid;
 buff.parent_proc.pid = task->parent->pid;
 int res = copy_to_user(info, &buff, sizeof(buff));
 if(res == 0) printk("success!");
 else printk("fail");
 return 0;
 //}
 }
 }
 return -1;
 }
```

How to implement this system call? Thanks